# How to get input parameter in child component Angular?

Tags: angular, angular5

In parent component I have:

```
<app-access-password [profileId]="getProfileId(kid.getId())"></app-access-password>
```

Where `getProfileId(kid.getId()` returns number if kid. I can see this value in template:

`{{getProfileId(kid.getId())}}` it is not empty.

WhenI try to get `profileId` value inside component `app-access-password`:

```
@Input() profileId: number;
constructor() {
   console.log(this.profileId)
}
```

I got undefined message. Why?

Comment: Because the value is not defined yet. Check again in `ngOnInit`, not in the constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to access after the view has been loaded, move it to ngOnInit() method

```
@Input() profileId: number;
ngOnInit() {
   console.log(this.profileId)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though the answer is accepted ,i would like to differ .
You can access it in `ngOnChanges()` . 
`ngOnChanges` is called even before `ngOnInint()` .

```
ngOnChanges(changes : SimpleChanges){
 //changes.profileId will store both the previous and the current value . 
}
```

so as soon as the `@Input()` kicks in(value is changed from `null` to a defined value) , `ngOnChanges` is automatically called so you don't have to wait for component `ngOnInit`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to load after `ngOnInit()`

```
@Input() profileId: number;
ngOnInit() {
   console.log(this.profileId)
}
ngOnChanges(){
// you can access value everytime `this.profileId` value changes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular life hooks design says, all input value you can access after `constructor`. 
 You can access it from `init` .

```
@Input() profileId: number;
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.profileId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Input() profileId: number;
ngOnInit() {

}
console.log(this.profileId)
```

you can access inside class any anywhere